# Centering a figure on tikz's x=0, not on the figure's actual center line

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, horizontal-alignment

I'm trying to get a figure made with `tikz` to be centered exactly on the figure's own internal x-axis. I don't want to use `\centering`, as at least with its default behaviour, `\centering` finds its own center line based on the actual width of the `tikzpicture` as a whole. What I'm looking for is a way to center it on a chosen point, completely disregarding the actual width of the figure.

MWE of `\centering`'s behaviour:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}\centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw (-3,0) -- (2,0);
            \path (0,2) node [shape=circle,draw]  {};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{This figure should be centered on x=0, marked by the circle. It isn't.}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In short, I'm looking for a way to take this exact figure, off-center line included, and place it inside the figure float in such a way that the circle at x=0 is what's centered above the caption (with the line off-center). Is such a thing possible? What does it involve?

Comment: If you add `\path (3,0);` to your picture, it is.... These are relative coordinates and Ti*k*Z computes the bounding box on the basis of the things you draw in the picture. The coordinates have no absolute meaning (unless you work with absolute page coordinates).

Comment: @marmot Oh, so the workaround is just to make an undrawn `\path` that alters the bounding box size? Makes sense, and seems to solve my problem just fine!

Comment: I wouldn't call it a workaround, but yes. Of course you could ask Ti*k*Z to make the bounding box symmetric around `(0,0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinates of a (non-overlay) `tikzpicture` have no absolute meaning because Ti*k*Z computes the bounding box on the basis of the things you draw in the picture. Of course, you can readjust the bounding box in such a way that the origin becomes the horizontal center of the bounding box. Either by hand, e.g. by adding `\path (3,0);` in this case, or write a style for it, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{make origin horizontal center of bounding box/.style={%
execute at end picture={%
\path let \p1=(current bounding box.west),\p2=(current bounding box.east)
in ({-max(-1*\x1,\x2)},\y1) ({max(-1*\x1,\x2)},\y1);
}}}
\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}\centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw (-3,0) -- (2,0);
            \path (0,2) node [shape=circle,draw]  {};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{This figure should be centered on x=0, marked by the circle. It
        isn't because the bounding box of a \textbackslash\texttt{tikzpicture}
        is computed on the basis of its contents.}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}\centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[make origin horizontal center of bounding box]
            \draw (-3,0) -- (2,0);
            \path (0,2) node [shape=circle,draw]  {};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{This figure should be centered on x=0, marked by the circle. It
        is now with the help of \texttt{make origin horizontal center of bounding box}.}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]