# Centering a TikZ picture around the main area when using scope

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a tikz picture containing scope and a textbox, located outside the main graphic (see figure below).

[image]

I obtained this figure with the following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering  
    \fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
            \node [
            above right,
            inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) 
            {\includegraphics[width=7.00cm,height=4.01cm]{example-image-duck}};
            \begin{scope}[
                x={($0.1*(image.south east)$)},
                y={($0.1*(image.north west)$)}]
                
    
                \draw[latex-, thick,black]  
                (4.2,5.7) -- (-3.2,8.5)
                node[above,black,fill=white, draw=black]{\small Left eye};
            \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}}%
    \adjustbox{trim={0cm 0cm 0cm 0},clip}{\usebox0}
    \caption{An example image to show concept}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

What I want, however, is that the whole picture would be centered around the main area (the figure of duck itself, added with includegraphics[width=7.00cm,height=4.01cm]{example-image-duck}). In other words, same type of centering as we would get without the textbox and arrow (see image below):

[image]

Browsing this site, I found that there are already some solutions for this problem, particularly [Centering a TikZ picture around an area](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/centering-a-tikz-picture-around-an-area) and also [Centering a figure on tikz's x=0, not on the figure's actual center line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/484189/centering-a-figure-on-tikzs-x-0-not-on-the-figures-actual-center-line). Yet somehow I am not able to successfully implement any of them, which is why I am asking you for help.

Comment: Do you want you textbox inside the fbox or outside of it?

Comment: At first consideration, I think that having it outside would be better, as this would allow easier trimming of the main graphics itself.

Comment: If thats the expected otuput: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpOMN.png You may want to place the `scope` environment inside of a `pgfinterruptboundingbox` environment in order to hide it from the bounding box calculation.

Comment: Yes, when I want to trim the main graphic itself, this does work, if I also change \includegraphics[width=7.00cm,height=4.01cm]{example-image-duck} with \includegraphics[width=7.00cm,height=4.01cm,trim={0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm},clip]{example-image-duck}. Furthermore, I can change fbox with mbox in case I do not want the frame, but still want for textboxes to be shown. However, the problem I have with this approach is that when such tikz picture is on new page, the spacing isnt adjusted (the textbox overlap with the header), if location of textbox is for example at (-3.2,14.5).

Comment: I can somehow correct that with \vspace{x cm}, but do you perhaps know more systematic approach? Also, similar problem happens (textbox can overlap with the figure caption) if the textbox location is for example at (-3.2,-2.5)

Comment: As John Kormylo answered my question, It is now time to clarify confusion that I created with the comments above: For trimming of the main graphics, it of course does not matter if the textboxes are in the fbox or not (as I wrongly said in my first comment), as this can be simply done by adding trim option to include graphics:                    \includegraphics[width=7.00cm,height=4.01cm,trim={0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm},clip]{example-image-duck}.

Comment: But for the trimming of the box itself, \adjustbox{trim={0cm 0cm 0cm 0},clip}{\usebox0} command is available (see John Kormylo answer in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/618780/tikz-cropping-image-without-misaligning-textboxes-and-arrows), if we use sbox0 option instead of fbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

[image: demo]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering  
    \fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
            \node [inner sep=0, above right] (image) at (0,0) 
            {\includegraphics[width=7.00cm,height=4.01cm]{example-image-duck}};
            \begin{scope}[
                x={($0.1*(image.south east)$)},
                y={($0.1*(image.north west)$)}]
                
    
                \draw[latex-, thick,black]  
                (4.2,5.7) -- (-3.2,8.5)
                node[above,black,fill=white, draw=black]{\small Left eye};
            \end{scope}
            \path ($(image.center)!-1!(current bounding box.west)$)% expand east border
                  ($(image.center)!-1!(current bounding box.east)$);% expand west border
    \end{tikzpicture}}%
    \adjustbox{trim={0cm 0cm 0cm 0},clip}{\usebox0}
    \caption{An example image to show concept}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In this particular case, it does the desired thing if I comment the line ($(0,0)!-1!(current bounding box.north)$). However, the solution does not work anymore if I for example add annother textbox, like\draw[latex-, thick,black] (4.2,5.7) -- (13.2,-6.5) node[above,black,fill=white, draw=black]{\small Left eye}; (though adding \path ($(0,0)!-1!(current bounding box.east)$); does seem to solve that problem). Moreover, is there a way to preserve above right in \node [inner sep=0] command? Otherwise the whole coordinate system changes.

Comment: Not a problem.  It was just easier to think of centering around the origin, but any named coordinate will do.

Comment: If you do not mind, I will just ask one question: What does !-1! in the path command exactly do?

Comment: `($(a)!-1!(b)$)` extrapolates a point the same distance but in the opposite direction from (a) to (b).  `\path` adds that point to the bounding box.